# Unable to edit anything inside a smart object?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, image-editing

Locked Layer Inside Smart Object

[image: Showing Smart Object in my Document]

I inserted an image into my document as a smart object. However, when I want to go make an edit to it the smart object is locked.

I unlock the layer, make my changes, and save it.

If I click save and save it as a psd but the changes aren't reflected in the smart object.

Everytime I go to open and edit the smart object it shows that it's locked again.

Answer (score 1):

You have placed an image to your Photoshop document. The image appeared as smart object. Smart object is essentially a linked image. You can do some geometrical transforms to it like to normal layers except they are losslessly reversible, because the content is taken from the original. All color editing is prohibited until you add an adjustment layer or right click and select "Edit contents". (see NOTE1)

"Edit contents" opens your image in a new tab. All edits are possible. The lock shows that your image has only a background layer - it cannot be transparent and it cannot be moved. (you probably placed a JPG.)

After editing the contents you must save the result exactly to the original place and format or you do not see anything changed. If your image was Filename.jpg and you save  it after editing  as Filename.psd, it's not the same. The edits aren't reflected to your document.

You can place the edited PSD, if you want to get it along.

Blur and other filters are allowed to smart objects. Photoshop generates "Smart filters" without asking. The original image stays intact.

Smart objects and smart filters (+ layer styles and adjustment layers) make edits easily reversible and you do not change the original. You can also keep the edits and change the image where the edits are used. These makes things a little confusing for beginners, but it's the very reason why Photoshop is more handy than low cost alternatives.

**NOTE1** If the smart object bothers you and you want an ordinary layer, you can right click and rasterize the smart object. That breaks the link to the original image file and flatten the smart object, if it happens to be a multilayer image. You can also make a "new smart object via copy" and rasterize it to keep the original easily available, if needed.